# How to protect server views and client views using loopback

Tags: javascript, node.js, angular-ui-router, loopbackjs, strongloop

I'm trying to protect my application's views based on roles. In laravel the solution is simply adding a middleware as part of the route parameters. Also would like to accomplish the same functionality on the client side using an Angular SPA app. Sorry I think these are two questions in one, anyways.

https://laravel.com/docs/5.1/authentication#protecting-routes

Any simple solution to accomplish this?

Comment: For sure it has to be done at least on the server-side, but I am interested in a way to do that as well. Interesting question

Answer (score 0):

In Angular you can implement the same logic in an Interceptor something like this..

```
app.factory('ApiInterceptor', function() {
    return {
         'request': function(config) {
               //check config.url against users roles somehow
               disallow = doesTheUserHaveTheCorrectRoles(config.url);
               //disallow the request to the API
               if(disallow){
                    alert('No!');
                    return false;
               }else{
                    return config;
               }
         }
    }
}
```

Check the documentation on HTTP Interceptors https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$http

Or you could do the same thing with a run block and do something when the location changes;

```
app.run(function ($rootScope) {
    $rootScope.$on("$locationChangeStart", function (event, next, current){
               disallow = doesTheUserHaveTheCorrectRoles(next);
               //disallow access to the next location
               if(disallow){
                    alert('No!');
                    return false;
               }else{
                    return config;
               }
    });
});
```

https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/module